# Suggestions for statistical model/approach to “Pattern recognition for non-uniform time data”

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

I have a dataset from which I would like to detect recurring patterns (i.e: daily, weekly, monthly). The dataset only contains a time stamp (datetime), and the spacing is non-uniform.

The observations in the data reflect the exact time when this one person passes my window. He does this several times a day (on a single day he walks by my window approx 10-30 times), and I am trying to see, if there is any pattern (there might also be some seasonality, sudden changes in previous behavior and other interesting stuff going on).

Does anyone have a suggestion for a statistical model/approach that might be helpful in figuring out if there is any pattern in this behavior? Hopefully, I’ll be able to predict when he will pass my window again ;) How would you approach this?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you map your data to a evenly spaced timeline, you could use autocorrelation to quickly detect periodic patterns. Might not be the most advanced approach, but will give you some insight.